# Coldfusion ajax html submit

Tags: mysql, ajax, coldfusion, tinymce, railo

I am using railo and attempting to submit a tinymce text area via ajax.

My problem is upon submission it seems that the html is stripped and the sql isn't actually updated.

here is my code:

```
function UpdateHome() {
  document.getElementById('UpdateProcessing').style.display = '';
  document.getElementById('HomeForm').style.display = 'none';
  ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm("HomeForm","action.cfm",HomeUpdateReturn);
  }

<form action="action.cfm" method="post" id="HomeForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="HomeUpdate" />
 <CFLOOP QUERY="FetchHome">
 <textarea id="HomeArea" name="HomeArea" class="tinymce" rows="20" cols="20"
 style="width:100%; height:500px" >#Body#</textarea>
 </CFLOOP>
 <input type="button" class="HomeSubmit" value="Save" onClick="UpdateHome();" /> 
</form>

<CFQUERY NAME="UpdateHome">
 UPDATE Content
 SET Body = '#HomeArea#'
 WHERE ID = 1
</CFQUERY>

<CFSET UdateHome     = ArrayNew(1)>
<CFSET UpdateHome[1]     = true>
<CFCONTENT TYPE="application/json" RESET="true">
<CFOUTPUT>#serializeJSON(UpdateHome)#</CFOUTPUT>
```

When I submit the form without ajax the sql works fine .

does anyone have any idea why this wont submit the html formatted text via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do before you submit the form is to call the javascript line

```
 tinymce.triggerSave()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

1. I don't believe you can use `ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm()` unless you are using cfform or unless you use `<cfajaximport ... />` to import the javascript.  Have you confirmed via Firebug or Chrome dev tools that the Javascript isn't throwing an error?  I suspect it is.  Change your `<form ... >` and `</form>` tags to `<cfform ...>` and `</cfform>` and try again.
2. Also, I don't think that is going to work as you expect since you have both the form and the form handler logic in the same file.  I would separate them.
3. You are referencing a `HomeUpdateReturn` return handler function which doesn't exist.  You need to write this function in your Javascript code.

You also have a couple other issues I just can't let pass without pointing out:

1. You should scope your variables.  In your update query you have `'#homearea#'`.  This could reference any `homearea` variable and may not be the one in the form scope you expect.  Change this to `#form.homearea#`.  This will ensure that only the variable in the form scope is used.
2. You **need** to use `<cfqueryparam ... />` in your query otherwise you leave yourself open to sql injection attacks.  So change the `'#homearea#'` to `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longchar" value="#form.homearea#" />`.  (Assuming in your database you are using an large text field)  Never allow unchecked user input to go directly into your query without using a parameterized query.

Comment: For sake of making this easily viewable I only included the pieces that were where the error could lie.

Comment: I am using CFAJAX IMPORT, I have a HomeUpdateReturn function created I just did not include it in the code above, These scripts run on separate pages, and coldfusion.ajax.submitform() works fine on a plain text area